# How can I increment integer field per ParentId(same way assignment rules auto calculate order)

Tags: apex, trigger

As the title suggests I just want it so that on insert/save/delete a number field on a custom object auto calculates the field so that the max value is the same as the size of the list for all records of the custom object with the same ParentId.

I thought it may of been as simple as the following but doesn't work:

```
public static void checkpriority(Client_Personal_Goal__c[] cgoals){
        list<Client_Personal_Goal__c> existingcgoal = new list<Client_Personal_Goal__c>();
        Set<Id> preclaraId = new set<Id>();
        for(Client_Personal_Goal__c cgoal : cgoals){ 
            preclaraId.add(cgoal.Related_Pre_Clarification__c);
        }    
        Integer temp = 0;
        existingcgoal = [select Id, Priority__c 
                         from Client_Personal_Goal__c 
                         where Related_Pre_Clarification__c in: preclaraId 
                         ORDER BY Priority__c ASC];
        for(Client_Personal_Goal__c cgoal : existingcgoal){ 
            temp = temp + 1; 
            cgoal.Priority__c =  temp;

        }
        if(existingcgoal != null && existingcgoal.size() > 0){
            update existingcgoal;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Rather than looping through `existingcgoal`, can you not just set `Priority__c = existingcgoal.size()`? Are you just trying to set `Priority__c` to the size of `List<Client_Personal_Goal__c>`?

Comment: No I am trying to get each record in the list to have a unique priority value from 1 to n, where n is the size of the list.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
public static void checkpriority(Client_Personal_Goal__c[] cgoals){
List<Client_Personal_Goal__c> lstClientPersonalGoalToUpdate = new List<Client_Personal_Goal__c>();//List to update Priority Count

Map<Id,Integer> mapClientPersonalGoaltoCount = new list<Id,Integer>();//Map of Cilent Personal Id to child count 

Set<Id> preclaraId = new set<Id>();

for(Client_Personal_Goal__c cgoal : cgoals){ 
    preclaraId.add(cgoal.Related_Pre_Clarification__c);
}    

Integer temp = 0;
existingcgoal = [];

for(Client_Personal_Goal__c cgoal : select Id, Priority__c 
                                    from Client_Personal_Goal__c 
                                    where Related_Pre_Clarification__c in: preclaraId 
                                    ORDER BY Priority__c ASC){ 

    //If map doesn't contain add add the id with count as 1
    if(!mapClientPersonalGoaltoCount.containsKey())
        mapClientPersonalGoaltoCount.put(cgoal.Id, 1);
    //If map already had Id update the count by adding plus 1   
    else
        mapClientPersonalGoaltoCount.put(cgoal.Id, mapClientPersonalGoaltoCount.get(cgoal.Id)+1);
}

for(Id clientPersonalId : mapClientPersonalGoaltoCount.keySet()) {
    lstClientPersonalGoalToUpdate.add(new Client_Personal_Goal__c(Id=clientPersonalId,
                                                                  Priority__c =mapClientPersonalGoaltoCount.get(clientPersonalId));
}

update lstClientPersonalGoalToUpdate;
```

}

Comment: I get the following error which: list must have exactly 1 type argument. It looks like its coming from line 4:  Map<Id,Integer> mapClientPersonalGoaltoCount = new list<Id,Integer>();//Map of Cilent Personal Id to child count

Comment: I fixed up that line to Map<Id,Integer> mapClientPersonalGoaltoCount = new Map<Id,Integer>(); along with other issues you had but I get the following error now: Method does not exist or incorrect signature: [Map].containsKey()

Comment: //If map doesn't contain add add the id with count as 1
    if(!mapClientPersonalGoaltoCount.containsKey())

Please edit the above line to  if(!mapClientPersonalGoaltoCount.containsKey(cgoal.Id))

Apologies for the typo

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the above error method does not exist or invalid signature because in the below line of code
`if(!mapClientPersonalGoaltoCount.containsKey())`
You are not specifying the key.
So the reason it's throwing you an error method does not exist or invalid signature.
Please pass the key in the above line and compile the code you will be able to do it.

Best Regards,

Nagendra